# Bash date command ongoing update

Tags: bash, date

Is there a way for `date` (or something similar) in bash to have an ongoing update each time a new line is piped to it?

I'm trying to take ongoing output, pipe through `awk` to prepend a timestamp, and then write that to a log file named with the correct date of write (for example `log.2018-06-21`). When the new day arrives, the output should automatically start writing to the new day's log file.

Put simply, `./my_server | awk >> log.date-of-write`

Here is what I tried (with format `%T` instead of `%F` for test purposes):

```
$ awk '{ print strftime("%F %T %Z:  ") $0; fflush(); }' |& tee -a "log.$(date +"%T")"
test1
2018-06-21 22:56:38 UTC:  test1
test2
2018-06-21 22:56:40 UTC:  test2
test3
2018-06-21 22:56:42 UTC:  test3
^C
$ ls
log.22:56:36
$ cat log.22\:56\:36 
2018-06-21 22:56:38 UTC:  test1
2018-06-21 22:56:40 UTC:  test2
2018-06-21 22:56:42 UTC:  test3
$
```

All the tests were written to the same file, because the original time was used in the format.

Comment: This is really, **really** slow. `date` is a separate executable, not part of the shell -- you're starting **a whole new program** every time you want to write a new line.

Comment: ...not saying you *can't* make this happen, but that you *shouldn't*. There's a reason conventional/longstanding log rotation systems have an external scheduler doing the rotation and sending a signal to trigger reopen. For that matter, since such tools exist, is there a reason you aren't using them?

Comment: The reason is that I'm new to this and unfamiliar with what you're talking about. Would you suggest `logrotate`? Or something else?

Comment: logrotate is indeed the standard/conventional/longstanding thing. If you're at a site that uses runit, you might also look at [svlogd](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html); similarly, if you're at a site that uses systemd (increasingly common these days), you get rotated and timestamped logging "for free" if you just send content from your daemons to stdout to be directed to the journal.

Comment: ...if you *are* having your logs rotated with logrotate, reopening them on a SIGHUP might look something like `trap 'exec >>"$log" 2>&1' HUP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done; what you need to do is periodically generate a new filename, check whether it's the same as the name you're writing output to, and re-open your stdout to point to the new location if they differ.

Note that the `printf %(...)T` idiom used in lieu of `date` is a recent feature, and may not be present if you're running an old version of bash. (You certainly *can* switch to `date`, but doing so would be much slower).

```
log_with_rotation() {
  local outfile_name outfile_curr line
  outfile_curr=
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf -v outfile_name 'log.%(%H:%M:%S)T' -1
    if [[ $outfile_name != "$outfile_curr" ]]; then
      outfile_curr=$outfile_name
      exec >"$outfile_name"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
}
```

When I run this:

```
your_program() {
  printf '%s\n' "Cluster one, line one" "Cluster one, line two"
  sleep 2
  printf '%s\n' "Cluster two, line one" "Cluster two, line two"
}

your_program | log_with_rotation
```

...I get two output files:

```
$ grep Cluster log.*
log.17:09:38:Cluster one, line one
log.17:09:38:Cluster one, line two
log.17:09:40:Cluster two, line one
log.17:09:40:Cluster two, line two
```

Comment: With `printf %(%F)T`, I'm getting 1970-01-01.
Similarly for `printf %(%H:%M:%S)T`, I'm getting 00:00:00.
Is that the sign I'm running an old version of bash?

Comment: Figured it out. Have to add `-1` as arg. `printf '%(%F)T' -1`

Comment: Shoot -- sorry 'bout that. (Learned something from the error, though; I actually thought -1 was still mandatory, but the code worked for me as originally given, testing on bash 4.4.23, so that's evidently something that changed over time).